# (.Net) Easy way to use Memory Mapped Files. Just like a variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, memory-management, shared-memory, memory-mapped-files

I'm developing an ASP.NET web application. It needs a lot of RAM. Therefore, I'm thinking of memory mapped files.

But, implementing memory mapped files is very exhausting. It needs to use those memory addresses, SizeOf operators and etc.. (I'm running out of time).

The current system is using a big **dictionary** to store those big amounts of data. All the classes are [Serializable]. **Is there a way to wrap up access to memory mapped files like this**,

```
(C# Psedo-code)    
var WrittingObject = new blablabla;
SetMMFVariable(name: "var1", value : WrittingObject);
var ReadingObject = GetMMFVariable(name: "var1");
```

**Is there any wrapping codes for memory mapped files in .NET? where I don't have to worry about those memory addresses and other stuff.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be a great candidate for a database! The problem you have is serializing/deserializing large amounts of information at once. If you need to read or update a small piece of information then you need to scan the entire file to update a SINGLE record. This is crazy expensive!

The workaround is to have some structured data model. You can either distribute the model read/writes to use many small files on the OS (subject to corruption, DISK issues, permission issues, multiple access & file locks) to get around the above serialization issue or you can go to an actual database that will allow you to query & update/insert the information you need.

For a structured model (c# is good at this) look at Sql Server Express
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-2017

For unstructured information (json) look at something non-relational like couchbase 
https://docs.couchbase.com/dotnet-sdk/2.7/start-using-sdk.html